# Unresolved reference: put

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, insert, put

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8812.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdKZf.png)

i changed the build.grade but is not working
also i tried to use the imports from the other class it dint work again
here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.6")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.6")
    implementation ("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2")
    implementation ("androidx.sqlite:sqlite-ktx:2.4.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

}
```

Comment: did you synced gradle successfully?